# `re.sub()` in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Say I have:

```
s = 'white male, 2 white females'
```

And want to "expand" this to:

```
'white male, white female, white female'
```

A more complete list of cases would be:

- 'two hispanic males, two hispanic females'

  - --> 'hispanic male, hispanic male, hispanic female, hispanic female'
- '2 black males, white male'

  - --> 'black male, black male, white male'

It seems like I am close with:

```
import re

# Do I need boundaries here?
mult = re.compile('two|2 (?P<race>[a-z]+) (?P<gender>(?:fe)?male)s')

# This works:
s = 'white male, 2 white females'
mult.sub(r'\g<race> \g<gender>, \g<race> \g<gender>', s)
# 'white male, white female, white female'

# This fails:
s = 'two hispanic males, 2 hispanic females'
mult.sub(r'\g<race> \g<gender>, \g<race> \g<gender>', s)
# ' ,  , hispanic males, hispanic female, hispanic female,'
```

What is creating the trip-up in the second case?

Bonus question: **Is there a method of pandas' Series that implements this functionality directly** instead of using `Series.apply()`?  Sorry to revise my question and waste anyone's time here.

For instance, on:

```
s = pd.Series(
    ['white male',
     'white male, white female',
     'hispanic male, 2 hispanic females',
     'black male, 2 white females'])
```

Is there a faster route than:

```
s.apply(lambda x: mult.sub(..., x))
```

Comment: Pandas does offer a bunch of vectorized string functions. My regex isn't the best, so translating everything from your problem into their functions is kinda complicated. But, reading their docs would probably get you close to solving the problem: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar--think it may be implementable with `.str.replace()` @DataSwede

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need to put paranthesis around `two|2` like `(two|2)` if you want to match either.

```
import re

mult = re.compile('(two|2) (?P<race>[a-z]+) (?P<gender>(?:fe)?male)s')
s = 'two hispanic males, 2 hispanic females'
mult.sub(r'\g<race> \g<gender>, \g<race> \g<gender>', s)
# 'hispanic male, hispanic male, hispanic female, hispanic female'
```

Comment: Thanks--just realized that also.  Otherwise you're catching mandatory 'tw' followed by either 'o' or '2'

Comment: @BradSolomon no problem.

Answer (score 9):

With regards to your "bonus" question, you can use `pandas.Series.str.replace`, which is part of the [`pandas.Series.str` methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#method-summary) which work with regex:

```
In [10]: import re

In [11]: import pandas as pd

In [12]: s = pd.Series(
    ...:     ['white male',
    ...:      'white male, white female',
    ...:      'hispanic male, 2 hispanic females',
    ...:      'black male, 2 white females'])

In [13]: mult = re.compile('two|2 (?P<race>[a-z]+) (?P<gender>(?:fe)?male)s')
    ...:

In [14]: s.str.replace(mult, r'\g<race> \g<gender>, \g<race> \g<gender>')
Out[14]:
0                                         white male
1                           white male, white female
2    hispanic male, hispanic female, hispanic female
3             black male, white female, white female
dtype: object
```

Whether or not these methods are significantly faster than `.apply` I don't know. I suspect that you'll never be very fast working with `object` dtypes.

Note, if found [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4694) regarding these methods being on the slow side. I suppose until they decide it is worth it to write out a Cythonized implementation then you probably can't hope for much.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your regex itself I'd go with the following one which is more general and optimized.

```
In [14]: mult = re.compile('(?:two|2) ([^,]+)')

In [15]: s = 'two hispanic males, 2 hispanic females'

In [16]: mult.sub(lambda x: x.group(1) + ' ' + x.group(1), s)
Out[16]: 'hispanic males hispanic males, hispanic females hispanic females'
```

But about the performance and applying the regex to a Pandas `Series` using a list comprehension is the best way to go:

```
In [29]: s = pd.Series(                                     
    ['white male',
     'white male, white female',
     'hispanic male, 2 hispanic females',
     'black male, 2 white females'])

In [30]: %timeit s.str.replace('(?:two|2) (?P<race>[a-z]+) (?P<gender>(?:fe)?male)s', r'\g<race> \g<gender>, \g<race> \g<gender>')
1000 loops, best of 3: 205 µs per loop

In [31]: %timeit s.apply(lambda x: mult.sub(lambda x: x.group(1) + ' ' + x.group(1), x))
10000 loops, best of 3: 148 µs per loop

In [32]: %timeit [mult.sub(lambda x: x.group(1) + ' ' + x.group(1), i) for i in s]
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.6 µs per loop
```

Comment: Is the noncapturing group in `(?:two|2)` needed here because you're not explicitly naming groups with `(?P<...>)`?  In other words, is that why the noncapturing notation is needed in this answer, but not with @Tai's?

Comment: @BradSolomon Yes because we don't need'em.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = ['Geeks', 'For', 'Geeks', 'is', 'portal', 'for', 'Geeks']
lst2 = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst, lst2)), columns =['Name', 'val'])

# \1 $1 \g<1>
df.replace(regex=r'(\w)(?P<ewe>\w)', value='\g<1>_\g<ewe>=')

## Output
           Name  val
0     G_e=e_k=s   11
1         F_o=r   22
2     G_e=e_k=s   33
3          i_s=   44
4  p_o=r_t=a_l=   55
5         f_o=r   66
6     G_e=e_k=s   77
```